# How to interactively colorize an image on javascript?

Tags: angular, web, html5-canvas

I'm developing a web application using Angular framework but I need a section where the user can color parts of the image (previously mapped by sections) or add indicators like colored dots.

All that section need to be get or saved to backend, mi question is which framework or library allows this type of interaction.

PD: I was thinking in threejs but I think it is too much for my requirement.

I attached an image to exemplify my question:
[image]

Comment: _"mi question is which framework or library allows this type of interaction."_ - why can't you build it yourself? It's quite straightforward to implement flood-fill in a `<canvas>` element, for example.

Comment: _"I was thinking in threejs but I think it is too much for my requirement."_ - D3 is for data-visualization, not for building colouring-in-books. (EDIT: gah, I thought you said d3, not threejs - but even then, threejs is for 3D models... but you described working with 2D images).

Comment: thank you four your comments, I will consider your opinions.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth I would use ECharts in combination of some color picker I guess. Echart will help you with the svg rendering, data plus visualisations (if needs be).

https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=geo-beef-cuts

https://zefoy.github.io/ngx-color-picker/